# How to display python output in splunk?

Tags: python, splunk

I am writing a code in python which will run sql select query and return the result. How do I display the output from python script in Splunk?

Currently I just have a python script running sql query and have tried importing `import splunklib.client as client`which fails as `[pylint] E0401:Unable to import 'splunklib.client'`

Tried this:

```
import mysql.connector
import splunklib.client as client

#splunk credentials
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8089
USERNAME = "admin"
PASSWORD = "yourpassword"

# Connect to splunk and log in 
service = client.connect(
    host=HOST,
    port=PORT,
    username=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD)
```

But it gives an error while importing library

I expect the output of python script which will be something like :

```
   STAGED = 1
   FAILED = 2
   VALIDATED =1
```

to be displayed in SPLUNK using python script itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass this command in commands.conf file. In stanza give command name and key value pair pass filename = python filename

[commandname]
filename = python.py

You can more knowledge on docs.splunk about commands.conf file

Comment: hello @Aman I am looking for a solution where I dont need to change anything on splunk conf but something in python script only .

Comment: Hi kanika.. The error you are getting is due to missing libraries.. you need to install those.. pip install splunk-sdk will work with sudo rights..